# Accessing global variables in function

Tags: php, global-variables, behavior

I just faced a piece of code which makes it possible accessing the variable by making it global and started thinking if it is different from other language approach/behavior

```
<?php
   $a1 = "WILLIAM";
   $a2 = "henry";
   $a3 = "gatES";
   echo $a1 . " " . $a2 . " " . $a3 . "<br />";
   fix_names();
   echo $a1 . " " . $a2 . " " . $a3;
   function fix_names()
   {
      global $a1; $a1 = ucfirst(strtolower($a1));
      global $a2; $a2 = ucfirst(strtolower($a2));
      global $a3; $a3 = ucfirst(strtolower($a3)); 
   }
 ?>
```

The code accesses variables defined outside the function and makes them global inside the function. This is unlikely in other languages. For example we write variables in global space in C and make them global, thus we can access them inside function. So we first make them global and then access them everywhere. In above code, we first access them inside the function (**also I did not understand how we can access $a1, $a2, $a3 inside function when they are not passed as an argument**) and then make them global. Is this because of any different behavior of PHP processor.

Also I did not understand how we can make variables global elsewhere away from its declaration.

Sorry this may not be a question asking exactly where the code is breaking, but I believe understanding why code is written in a particular manner and why it behaves in a particular manner is also important.

**Putting it (hopefully) in  much cleared words**

I want to know: inside a function when we create a global variable with the same name as the variable that already exist in an outer scope, it actually global-izes the variable in outer scope instead of creating a new global variable (with null value). Is it like that? And if yes isn't that different from other languages? So is there any reason behind such distinct behavior?

Comment: do you know when to use `global` inside a function...?? I am asking that because you said, "In above code, we first access them inside the function and then make them global."

Comment: tell me in short what you actually want to know...?? how to use global variables inside a function...??

Comment: @BlackCobra question appended

Comment: when you are calling a variable inside a function php will create a new variable for this function and after the function have been closed php will delete the variable instantly... but if you write `global` before calling a variable, php will not create a new variable for this function... php will search for the global variable with mentioned name and use the variable... then you can use the value of the variable... can edit the value too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the manual - http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

> The scope of a variable is the context within which it is defined. For the most part all PHP variables only have a single scope. This single scope spans included and required files as well.
>   ...
>   However, within user-defined functions a local function scope is introduced. Any variable used inside a function is by default limited to the local function scope.
>   ...
>   You may notice that this is a little bit different from the C language in that global variables in C are automatically available to functions unless specifically overridden by a local definition. This can cause some problems in that people may inadvertently change a global variable. In PHP global variables must be declared global inside a function if they are going to be used in that function.

This enables you to use the same `$var` name inside a function, without it reassigning the value-

```
$var = 'string';

function test(){
$var = 'new string';
return $var;
}
echo $var;  // echo's - string
test();     // echo's - new string
```

Comment: so when we make a variable global with same name defined in outer-scope, then that variable is made global instead of declaring a new global variable?

Comment: If you declare it `global` inside the function and the value- `$var = 'string'; function test(){global $var; $var = 'new string';return $var;}` It will retain the global value `echo $var; // echo's string`, until you call the function `echo test(); // Everytime after you echo $var it will echo 'new string' instead of 'string'`

Answer (score 1):

In php functions has their own scope, thus if you declare the variable elsewhere outside the function it will not visible inside it. To use them inside the function you need to declare it global. Usually, I use [Registry](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/registry.html) pattern to not polute global scope and store all global objects which I will use later.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using sessions. You can define you variables in file file1.php like this:

```
session_start();    
$_SESSION['a'] = 'William';
```

Then you can access any session variable in file file2.php like this:

echo $_SESSION['a'];

Comment: are you crazy...?? he is still in the same document... I don't understand why you are using `$_SESSION`...?? and from where you get `file1.php`...??

Answer (score 0):

Please find a nice article on Global variables in php - It will tell you about various global variables that exist in Php Language and how to use and access these variables and their purpose.

Reference : https://www.w3elearners.com/php/global-variables/